# How to create restricted Api Key to use directions api?

Tags: android, google-maps, google-cloud-firestore, api-key, map-directions

i'm creating an app that's draw routes between users using only firestore to update users location.

the problem is to use direction api i need Restricted key using 
(server IP addresses)
what should i do ? i don't have server i'm using only firestore

Comment: What do you actually want to restrict?

Comment: if you are going to put your app in production you need "Application restrictions"
(none - http referrers , Ip addresses , android apps - ios apps) 
so after searching i found out that to use directions api u need Ip addresses restriction 
i don't know how to do it or what i need to do it

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about the use of a third party service and not about programming,

Comment: Do you send Directions API request directly from the app?

Comment: @xomena yes and it's works as long as my key restriction is none , once i change it to android i get error asking me to use ip server restrictions

Comment: It's correct. Web services like Directions API, Geocoding API, Distance Matrix API are supposed to be called from server, not from mobile app directly. So you will need put an intermediate server in order to call directions with protected API key.

Comment: how can i do that ? i don't have experience with servers , so how can i get started and what should i search for ? @xomena

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since your application is using a web service (Directions API), I believe you'll have to do the following to secure your API key:

- **Apply an API restriction on the API key.** This action narrows the scope of the API key to the APIs you associate with the key.
- **Obfuscate or encrypt the API key.**
  This action complicates key scraping attempts directly from the application.
- **Use CA pinning or certificate pinning to verify the server resources are valid.** CA pinning checks that a server's certificate was issued by a trusted certificate authority, and prevents Man-In-The-Middle attacks that could lead to a third party discovering your API key. Certificate pinning goes further by extracting and checking the public key included in the server certificate. Pinning is useful for mobile clients communicating directly with Google servers, as well as mobile clients communicating with the developer's own proxy server.
- **Use a proxy server.** The proxy server provides a solid source for interacting with the appropriate Google Maps Platform API.

More can be found in our public documentation **On mobile apps that use Maps Web Service APIs** of this **[Protecting API Keys](https://developers.google.com/maps/api-key-best-practices#best_practice_list)**

Answer (score 0):

For Android application, you may restrict your Google Maps API key with "Android apps" .

Based on the [docs:](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-sdk/get-api-key#restrict_key)

> To restrict an API key:
>
> 1. Go to the [Google Cloud Platform Console](https://console.cloud.google.com).
> 2. From the Project drop-down menu, select the project that contains the API key you want to secure.
> 3. From the  Navigation menu, select **APIs & Services > Credentials**.
> 4. On the **Credentials** page, click the name of the API key that you want to secure.
> 5. On the **Restrict and rename API key** page, set the restrictions: Application restrictions:
>
>    - Select **Android apps** and follow the instructions.
>    - Click + **Add package name and fingerprint**.
>    - Enter your package name and SHA-1 certificate fingerprint. For example: `com.example.android.mapexample`
>        `BB:0D:AC:74:D3:21:E1:43:67:71:9B:62:91:AF:A1:66:6E:44:5D:75`

Comment: 1st : ty for answering 
2nd : to use directions api you need "IP addresses (web servers, cron jobs, etc.)." restriction 
check this link (take a look at 'Restrict the API key' 5th step )
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/directions/get-api-key

Comment: Can you confirm if you will use this for your android application? (as it was added on your tags).

Comment: yes but  once i change my key restrictions to android i get error asking me to use ip server restrictions